# Could hysteria make people develop true symptoms of some disease without actually being sick of that disease?

Tags: social-psychology

There is an episode in [Dr. House series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airborne_(House)) in which there is a passager on board of an airplane and he starts to contract some symptoms and Cuddy tells him that it's meningococcal disease. Later in the plot, it's discovered that the passenger's disease is not meningitis and it's noticed that the crew is suffeting [mass hysteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_hysteria). The reaction of this Hysteria on Cuddy develops with her having exactly the symptoms of meningococcal disease. I got curious with this: Is it possible to have people to develop "true" symptoms on some occasion of mass hysteria?

There is also an episode in another series in which people start to feel sick and the psychologist says that perhaps people is not sick and that this could be only the power of suggestion. That it, people could be feeling sick because they think they are (in the context of the series).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answer to question is in first line of linked wiki